# aiohttp.Timeout and asyncio.InvalidStateError

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I'm using python 3.4.3 to periodically send requests to multiple urls.
Here is the coroutine I wrote (I've omitted some errors handling to simplify the code):

```
@asyncio.coroutine
def ping(url, interval, session, *, loop):
    while True:
        try:
            with aiohttp.Timeout(interval):
                resp = yield from session.get(url)
                resp.close()

        except asyncio.TimeoutError:
            # continue sending requests anyway
            continue

        yield from asyncio.sleep(interval)
```

I'm starting multiple `ping` coroutines using `asyncio.gather`.
But sometimes when the server responds too long I'm getting `InvalidStateError` exception:

```
Exception in callback <bound method Future.set_result of Future<CANCELLED>>(None,)
handle: Handle(<bound method Future.set_result of Future<CANCELLED>>, (None,))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/asyncio/events.py", line 39, in _run
    self._callback(*self._args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/asyncio/futures.py", line 298, in set_result
    raise InvalidStateError('{}: {!r}'.format(self._state, self))
asyncio.futures.InvalidStateError: CANCELLED: Future<CANCELLED>
```

The script continues to work, but how can I silence this traceback? Is it a bug or is that something I'm doing wrong?

The only thought I have is that when the web-server eventually responds, asyncio (or aiohttp) tries to set restult to the `Future` that was already cancelled.

**EDIT:**

Here is how I start that `ping` coroutine:

```
@asyncio.coroutine
def main(loop, rules, session):
    tasks = [ping(url, interval, session, loop=loop)
             for url, interval in rules]
    try:
        yield from asyncio.gather(*tasks, loop=loop)
    except Exception:
        print('Cancelled!', file=sys.stderr)
        traceback.print_exc()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    rules = [('http://localhost:8080/1/', 5),
             ('http://localhost:8080/2/', 10)]

    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    try:
        conn = aiohttp.TCPConnector(verify_ssl=False)
        with aiohttp.ClientSession(connector=conn) as session:
            loop.run_until_complete(main(loop=loop,
                                         rules=rules,
                                         session=session))
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('Interrupted. Exiting', file=sys.stderr)
```

Comment: Can you provide code to test? With session creation, `gather` and event loop.

Comment: It's not clear what future is cancelled. Would you provide more info?

Comment: I couldn't catch this exception on win/python 3.5. How often it's happen? Can you test your code with python 3.5 (may be it's ver. 3.4 specific bug)?